# netsuite oneworld customer statement

Tags: netsuite

in netsuite 2018.1, the customer data can be shared between subsidiaries, however, I cannot use script/workflow to generate the statement for the specified subsidiary, every statements generated are belong to the primary subsidiary of those client （eg. customer ABC, it has outstanding in boyh sub. A & sub. B, primary sub. is srt to A, only A's statement can be generated）

as we need to get the pdf files per customers, and we have hundreds customers, we will have to use other ways than the official generate statements function.

is there anyway to do this?

we are currently using ss1.0 nlapiprintrecord but it couldnt do

Comment: Did you ever come across a decent solution for this? We are encountering the same issue now. I'm thinking that it may come down to scripting a solution with a specific subsidiary, similar to this: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/80239/

Comment: It has not been solved. I check this answer, not sure why it provided a user event script for sample, it seems that it would like to change the Primary Subsidiary when there is an action from user and then save the statement, but Primary Subsidiary could not be changed once the customer has transaction(s). 

And for sdate.subsidairy, i tried it before i post this question, in suitelet, it just useless and nothing happens.